# Create a property of object with the value of variable

Tags: php

I don't know how to explain this, but I think the example is clear:

```
if($text == "libelle")
    $obj->libelle = $valeur;
else if($text == "numero")
    $obj->numero = $valeur;
else if($text == "commentaire")
    $obj->commentaire = $valeur;
else if($text == "date")
    $obj->date = $valeur;
```

Well, what I'm looking for is replace the if-statement with something like this
`$obj->(the value of $text) = $valeur;`

Comment: Try - `$obj->{$text}= $valeur;`

Comment: you can use `$obj->{$text} = $valeur`